# How to set permission for /dev/kvm

Tags: android-studio

Even after properly installing the Pixel 2 device emulator, Android Studio is giving an error that "The user doesn't have permission to use kvm(/dev/kvm).

Changed the permission with the command "chmod u+x /dev/kvm". But that didn't work.The character-device file became executable but still the error persists. Android device emulator refused to open.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your distribution, this file might be owned (and writable) by a generic group (e.g., "kvm-users", "kvm", "virt-admins", ...). If this is the case (you can check with any file manager), the easiest solution is to make your user a member of this group.

Comment: This.  ivan@darkstar:~$ ls -l /dev/kvm
crw-rw---- 1 root kvm 10, 232 Mar 17 19:08 /dev/kvm
ivan@darkstar:~$ groups
ivan adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare kvm webdev
ivan@darkstar:~$